# validar datos con ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema tengo una tabla en mysql que lleno con insert  y necesito hacer una comprobación si existen registros insertados.Con ajax envió datos a la pagina recargasal.php y debe devolver una repuesta con echo 1 o 0 según la tabla tiene o no registro pero no funciona. Si existen datos insertados  debería mostrar un mensaje. Gracias adjunto codigo del script y php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function recarga(){

   var ncomp= document.getElementById('ncomp').value;
   var dataString = 'ncomp='+ncomp;

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/recargasal.php",
            data: dataString,


            success: function (data){


           if( data == 1){
              alertify.alert("Atención","Primero debe eliminar productos seleccionados");
              return false;


             }else if (data == 0){



              javascript:location.reload();

            }
    }
    });
    }

</script>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
// connect to database
require_once "../data/conexion.php";

$ncomp = $_POST['ncomp'];

$sql3 = ("SELECT from salidas where salidas.comp_sal= '$ncomp' ");
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {

    echo '1';

} else {

    echo '0';
}

?>
```

Comment: Te falta definir los campos en tu sql `SELECT from salidas where salidas.comp_sal= '$ncomp' `

Comment: Cuál es el error o en que te falla? has intentado imprimir `$ncomp`en php? regresa lo que esperas?

Comment: Muchas gracias zeross me falta el * en el select.